# Passing Docker options using Dockerfile

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ecs

I am using AWS ECS to run Docker-based tasks. Since ECS agent task definitions don't support all Docker options, I'm looking for some workaround to pass these options to the `docker run` command.

Is it possible to pass Docker options like `--memory-swappiness`, `--memory-swap`, etc. using Dockerfiles?

Comment: You are not alone in this issue https://github.com/aws/amazon-ecs-agent/issues/502 and for `memory-swapiness`it has been added (https://github.com/aws/amazon-ecs-agent/issues/790).

Answer (score 1):

You should use something like docker compose for that. Docker compose allows to specify parameters for you containers. In contrast Dockerfile configures your image. For example to limit resources you just create resources section in you compose.yml. Note that swappiness is an obsolete parameter.

See link: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#resources

```
version: '3'
services:
  redis:
    image: redis:alpine
    deploy:
      resources:
        limits:
          cpus: '0.50'
          memory: 50M
        reservations:
          cpus: '0.25'
          memory: 20M
```

Comment: There are Docker options which ECS agent doesnt support . I am looking any other alternatives

Comment: What about using docker-machine to deploy your containers? Docker-machine support AWS.